# In Javascript does async await wait for all nested functions to complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

In the example below I need to reset some values before making the fetchData call in the fetch method. Does async await wait for all functions in the reset method to complete before continuing?

```
fetch = async () => {
  await this.reset();
  this.props.fetchData();
};

reset = () => {
  this.props.resetFilter();
  this.props.resetClient();
  this.props.resetUser();
};
```

Or do you have to do something like below?

```
fetch = () => {
  this.reset().then(() => {
    this.props.fetchData();
  });
};

reset = async () => {
  await this.props.resetFilter();
  await this.props.resetClient();
  await this.props.resetUser();
};
```

Thanks :)

Comment: reset functions return a promise?

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq no they don't return a promise. They are actions which will reset values in a reducer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`async`/`await` does not magically deal with asynchronous function.
It is a syntax addition that allows you to easier work with promises.

So whenever a function returns a Promise, you need to wait for it explicitly.

Either by writing `await` in front of each if you want to execute them in order, as you have shown in your second example:

```
reset = async () => {
  await this.props.resetFilter();
  await this.props.resetClient();
  await this.props.resetUser();
};
```

Or if you want to allow that those asynchounous function to interleave `Promise.all`:

```
reset = async () => {
  await Promise.all([
    this.props.resetFilter(),
    this.props.resetClient(),
    this.props.resetUser()
  ])
};
```

If you do not wait for the Promises like in your first example:

```
reset = () => {
  this.props.resetFilter();
  this.props.resetClient();
  this.props.resetUser();
};
```

then the promise chain is broken for that three call, this might not look like be a problem at first, especially if you assume that they always resolve. But can result in an unhandled rejection if on of this promises is rejected.

Answer (score 1):

This function returns undefined without waiting for all function calls to be settled.

```
reset = () => {
  this.props.resetFilter();
  this.props.resetClient();
  this.props.resetUser();
};
```

If you want to make sure that a value is returned only if all calls are settled, you would need to await (or chain promises, or ...)

Thus

```
reset = async () => {
  await this.props.resetFilter();
  await this.props.resetClient();
  await this.props.resetUser();
};
```

is one correct way to go to archive your desired behaviour.